# "STDERR: The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot." error while doing vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I'm getting the following error when doing `vagrant up`.

`STDERR: The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the 'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured properly and try again.`

I'm using vagrant 1.7.2 and virtual box 4.3.22

When I try to start VM using VB GUI, my system simply crashes with blue screen of death. Any ideas on on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using vagrant 1.8.1 and virtualbox 5.0.12. After some research, I found out that you cannot run a 64 bit VM in your PC if hardware acceleration (VT-x) is disabled. You can turn this setting on/off in the BIOS.

In my case, this was not an option cause I was running vagrant from another VM which doesn't support this option so I used 32 bit box and disabled hardware acceleration. To do this, add this to your Vagrantfile configuration:

```
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hwvirtex", "off"]
  end
```

This worked for me.